# Getting Error when using caching in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading my modal HTML page for first time and getting proper data ,but if i try to load second time I am getting an error ,

Please find my JS code below,

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
var cacheData = cache.get('xml');

if (!cacheData) {
    MyRestApi.getData($scope.data1).then(function(response) {
        cacheData = response;
        cache.put('xml', cacheData);
    });
} else {
    var processdata = cache.get('xml');
}
```

In my MyRestApi.js I am using the below code,

```
getData: function(Key) {
    return $http.get(baseURL + '/getDetails/' + Key, {
        headers: header,
        cache: true
    });
}
```

This is the first time I am using $cache in angular JS, please let me know why I am getting this error. I am loading the same modal page for second time and I am getting this error.
Getting angular.js:13568 Error: [$cacheFactory:iid] CacheId 'cacheId' is already taken!

Comment: When you set `cache: true` the get request is cached automatically. If you want to manipulate the cache manually then you should set the `cache` property to $cacheFactory object you just created. But do you really want that?

Comment: Is it possible to get directly like $scope.cache without using $cacheFactory, if it caches automatically how can I get the cache value from MyRestApi to JS code.  I need to set the data for only once and get it for second time where the data is very huge and taking long time to load. $scope.cache.put('xml',cacheData) and get using $scope.cache.get('xml') , please advise Is that the way you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enough:

```
getData: function(Key) {
    return $http.get(baseURL + '/getDetails/' + Key, {
        headers: header,
        cache: true
    });
}
```

The first time you will get the data, it will be stored in a http cache. The second time you make the same request, it will pass the cached value instead of fetching it again. Just look at the network tab in dev tools to confirm.

This is however only true if you have a single page application, reloading (f5) the page will reset the cache.